# Convert a pice of code to class

Tags: java, android, class

I have a problem with create a separate class in jave
I have this part of code

```
private class Read_from_db extends AsyncTask <String, Long, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Read.this);
    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.dialog.setMessage("Wait\nSome SLOW job is being done...");
    this.dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            //txtMsg.append("\n");
            // obtain a list of from DB
                String TABLE_NAME = "classicpoems__poet_header";
                String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
             //   String _ID = "_id";
                String COLUMN_NAME = "poet_name";
                String COLUMN_CENTURY = "century_start";
                String [] columns ={COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_CENTURY};

            Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,null, null, null, null, COLUMN_ID);
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Read.this, R.layout.list_item, c, 
                       new String[] {COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_CENTURY}, new int[] {R.id.list_item_text_id,R.id.list_item_text_main,R.id.list_item_text_sub}, 0);

            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_poet_name);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Toast.makeText(Read.this, e.getMessage(), 1).show();
                Log.i(TAG,  e.getMessage());
            }
        db.close();
        return null;
    }
    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
    if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
    this.dialog.dismiss();
    }
    // cleaning-up, all done
    this.dialog.setMessage("Done");

    }
}
```

That must repeat each time an activity loads (but with some changes for example `TABLE_NAME` and `R.id.list_poet_name`  `columns`  and ..)
I think repeating this code is not a professional way so I want to convert this to a separate class and in each activity I use it
But I don't know how to do it..(I tried but I always get error for example I don't know how to define context for `SimpleCursorAdapter` 
or make Toast work here can you help me how to convert this code to a separate class

Here Is my class code

```
   package co.tosca.persianpoem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Get_data extends AsyncTask<String, Long, Void> {
//Context context;
public String TABLE_NAME;
public String COLUMN_ID;
public String COLUMN_NAME;
public String COLUMN_CENTURY;
public String[] columns;
public int target;
private String DATABASE_NAME;
private static final String  SDcardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
private String DbPath = SDcardPath + "/Tosca/" + DATABASE_NAME;
private static final String TAG ="DatabaseHelper";
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private Activity callingActivity;
public int adapter_list;

//public Get_data(Context context){
  //  this.context=context;
  //  DATABASE_NAME="persian_poem.db";
//}


public Get_data(Activity activity) {
    callingActivity = activity;
}
public Get_data() {
    TABLE_NAME="classicpoems__poet_header";
    COLUMN_ID="_id";
    COLUMN_NAME = "poet_name";

}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    this.dialog.setMessage("Wait\nSome SLOW job is being done...");
    this.dialog.show();
}



@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        // obtain a list of from DB
        //    String TABLE_NAME = "classicpoems__poet_header";
         //   String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
         //   String _ID = "_id";
         //   String COLUMN_NAME = "poet_name";
         //   String COLUMN_CENTURY = "century_start";
          //  String [] columns ={COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_CENTURY};

        Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,null, null, null, null, COLUMN_ID);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(callingActivity, adapter_list, c, 
                   new String[] {COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_CENTURY}, new int[] {R.id.list_item_text_id,R.id.list_item_text_main,R.id.list_item_text_sub}, 0);


        ListView list = (ListView)callingActivity.findViewById(target);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(callingActivity, e.getMessage(), 1).show();
            Log.i(TAG,  e.getMessage());
        }
    db.close();

    return null;
}


protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
    dialog.dismiss();

}
}
```

and when I want to use it I use this codes

```
enter code here Get_data poet_name=new Get_data();
        poet_name.TABLE_NAME="classicpoems__poet_header";
        poet_name.COLUMN_ID = "_id";
        poet_name.COLUMN_NAME = "poet_name";
        poet_name.COLUMN_CENTURY = "century_start";
        poet_name.columns =new String[]{"_id","poet_name","century_start"};
        poet_name.adapter_list=R.layout.list_item;
        poet_name.target=R.id.list_poet_name;
        poet_name.execute();
```

But I get error ..Can you help me to find my mistakes?

I changed initial code to   `Get_data poet_name=new Get_data(this);` but I am getting error yet here is part of logcat

```
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.tosca.persianpoem/co.tosca.persianpoem.Read}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at co.tosca.persianpoem.Get_data.onPreExecute(Get_data.java:54)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at co.tosca.persianpoem.Read.onCreate(Read.java:65)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
01-06 04:25:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3244):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You are calling the wrong initializer for Get_data. Use this code (assuming you are calling from your activity: 
Get_data poet_name=new Get_data(this);

Comment: Thanks my friend but I still get error..I attached logcat code..I think my class have problem..an I right?

Comment: It looks like you are having trouble initializing your activity.  You need to debug your initialization.  Among other things, this code is never executed:  public Get_data() {
    TABLE_NAME="classicpoems__poet_header";
    COLUMN_ID="_id";
    COLUMN_NAME = "poet_name";

}
because you are not calling that method, but the one above it when you start up your app.

Comment: I tried to just clean all my code and replace a simple cod in doin background method but I still get error..Where I am doing wrong ..In calling class or entire class is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a separate class in its own file.  Make it public, so other classes can see it, and give it some creation parameters.

Pass the calling Activity to the class, then you can use that value for calls like toast that require the current Activity.

```
public class Read_from_db extends AsyncTask <String, Long, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Read.this);
    private Activity callingActivity;
    public Read_from_db(Activity activity) {
        callingActivity = activity;
    }


    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.dialog.setMessage("Wait\nSome SLOW job is being done...");
    this.dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            //txtMsg.append("\n");
            // obtain a list of from DB
                String TABLE_NAME = "classicpoems__poet_header";
                String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
             //   String _ID = "_id";
                String COLUMN_NAME = "poet_name";
                String COLUMN_CENTURY = "century_start";
                String [] columns ={COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_CENTURY};

            Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,null, null, null, null, COLUMN_ID);
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Read.this, R.layout.list_item, c, 
                       new String[] {COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_CENTURY}, new int[] {R.id.list_item_text_id,R.id.list_item_text_main,R.id.list_item_text_sub}, 0);

            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_poet_name);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(callingActivity, e.getMessage(), 1).show();
                Log.i(TAG,  e.getMessage());
            }
        db.close();
        return null;
    }
    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
    if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
    this.dialog.dismiss();
    }
    // cleaning-up, all done
    this.dialog.setMessage("Done");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help..I used contractor and now I can use current activity...But I have two problem first  `findViewById` is undefined and second If I want to change `String [] columns` from my activity how I can define it?Can I create a new method in  doInBackground method?

Comment: if you pass an activity to your class, you can use callingActivity.findViewById()

Comment: You can also add a String[] parameter to your creation of your class

Comment: Thanks man...I fixed that error but I cant use it yet..I added my class to  post..Can you tack a lock at it and show me my mistakes?

Comment: Thanks my friend but I still get error..I attached logcat code..I think my class have problem..an I right?

Answer (score 0):

(I hope I understood your issue correctly.)
Here is what I would suggest:

Create a separate class from the code above with a constructor having SimpleCursorAdapter type as parameter. Create `Read_from_db` object with `SimpleCursorAdapter` having table and column values as you wish and use the same in doInBackground method.

Comment: Thanks for your help but sorry I didn't get your mean..:( can you explain a bit more :),Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor in the AsyncTask class where you would pass the Context:

```
Context ctx;
public Read_from_db(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
```

Context ctx is a global class variable, and you can use it in place of Read.this

Comment: Thanks dear friend,now I can use context

Answer (score 0):

Simply make contructor of your custom class like this:

```
public class Read_from_db extends AsyncTask<String, Long, Void> {
Context context;
private ProgressDialog dialog;

public Read_from_db(Context context){
    this.context=context;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "dialog title", "dialog message.....");
}



@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //do your work here


    return null;
}


protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
    dialog.dismiss();

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed my first problem but now I have problem with `findviewbyid` that is undefined :(

Comment: Right click your project and click **Build Project**. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks I fixed that problem but I have some problem with my class..Can you tack a look at first post again?I added some logs there..maybe you can help me about my new problem..Thanks

Comment: Write your async class as i mention by me or @HaIR and you have to call this class from activity like                                 `new Get_data(this).execute();`

Comment: Thanks for your help..At the first I must define my variables and then use that code?because I want to define table_name and .. and my class use this variables and get data from database..